# DH parameters correct but the MATLAB plot isn't accurate

Tags: matlab, dh-parameters

```
%L(i) = Link([theta(i) D(i) a(i) Alpha(i)   
L(1) = Link([0 0 10 0]);
L(2) = Link([0 0 10 pi/2]);
L(3) = Link([0 0 20 pi/2]);
L(4) = Link([0 0 10 -pi/2]);

rob = SerialLink(L);

rob.name= "new robot";

rob.plot([0 0 0 0]);
```

given the MATLAB code and DH parameters in the code above, and the robot in the image shown[image]

why does plotting it results in the third joint oriented incorrectly? I'm assuming my parameters are incorrect but I don't know at this point.

any tips or help greatly appreciated :)

Comment: What do you mean when you say it's plotted incorrectly? Can you edit your question to include the result you're seeing?

Comment: the third joint is oriented incorrectly, if you run this code you'll the result is not the same as the picture im  going for

Comment: I'm on my phone until the start of January, don't have access to Matlab anymore, and never had the Corke Robotics Toolkit installed. If I had to guess, I don't know why you have three entries for alpha, but I also can't see what you're seeing, so just a guess.

Comment: You need to draw the frame transforms for each DH frame in your picture. It is not clear if the matlab code is correct or the picture is correct, or maybe both are wrong. You need to edit your question to clarify what and where axis are defined. Sometimes labeling the frames by hand helps you understand what you want to then figure out what went wrong.